# I don't have the 14 directory

Tags: 2013, log, windows-server-2012-r2

I'am currently running a windows server 2012 version and I don't have the "C:\Program files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS". Instead in the "14" directory I only have "CONFIG" and "TEMPLATE" directories.
I would like to see the .log file to see the error that matching with the correlation ID I got.

Comment: The log files should be present in 15/LOGS.

Comment: The logs can be setup to be stored anywhere. I would look for a specific drive on the computer used for logs (that's a very common setup)

Comment: Or , as Nadeem says, if this is a SharePoint 2013 environment, first look in the 15 folder

Comment: Or Sharepoint isn't even installed if there is no 14 or 15 hive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below powershell command to get the configuration details of the diagostics. You'll see a property "LogLocation" and check if you get the logs at that location

```
Get-SPDiagnosticConfig
```